# groovy list indexOf

Tags: regex, groovy

If I have a list with following elements

```
list[0] = "blach blah blah"
list[1] = "SELECT something"
list[2] = "some more text"
list[3] = "some more text"
```

How can I find the index of where the string starts with SELECT.

I can do `list.indexOf("SELECT something");`

But this is a dynamic list. `SELECT something` wont always be `SELECT something`. it could be `SELECT somethingelse` or anything but first word will always be `SELECT`.

Is there a way to apply regex to the indexOf search?

Comment: I would stray away from RegEx in java for performance issues, but take a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/ . Off the top of my head, I don't think there is a simple way of doing this, except manually iterating through your array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex in find:

```
def list = ["blach blah blah", "SELECT something", "some more text", "some more text"]

def item = list.find { it ==~ /SELECT \w+/ }

assert item == "SELECT something"

list[1] = "SELECT somethingelse"

item = list.find { it ==~ /SELECT \w+/ }

assert item == "SELECT somethingelse"
```

Answer (score 24):

```
def list = ["blach blah blah", "SELECT something", "some more text", "some more text"]
def index = list.findIndexOf { it ==~ /SELECT \w+/ }
```

This will return the index of the first item that matches the regex `/SELECT \w+/`. If you want to obtain the indices of *all* matching items replace the second line with

```
def index = list.findIndexValues { it ==~ /SELECT \w+/ }
```